# Excel macro out of memory error

Tags: excel, outlook, macros, out-of-memory, vba

really hopeful of getting some help!

I'll start by saying I didn't write this code (someone far smarter then me did!)

If anyone can shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated. it did run for a little bit, but while we were scaling up, I started experiencing issues.

the whole code that I'm getting the error with:

```
Option Explicit

Public ns As Outlook.Namespace

Private Const EXCHIVERB_REPLYTOSENDER = 102
Private Const EXCHIVERB_REPLYTOALL = 103
Private Const EXCHIVERB_FORWARD = 104

Private Const PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED =     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"
Private Const PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME =     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040"
Private Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS =     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
Private Const PR_RECEIVED_BY_ENTRYID As String =     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003F0102"

' Locates best matching reply in related conversation to the given mail     message passed in as oMailItem
Private Function GetReply(oMailItem As MailItem) As MailItem
Dim conItem As Outlook.Conversation
Dim ConTable As Outlook.Table
Dim ConArray() As Variant
Dim MsgItem As MailItem
Dim lp As Long
Dim LastVerb As Long
Dim VerbTime As Date
Dim Clockdrift As Long
Dim OriginatorID As String

Set conItem = oMailItem.GetConversation ' Let Outlook and Exchange do the hard lifting to get entire converstion for email being checked.
OriginatorID = oMailItem.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString(oMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_RECEIVED_BY_ENTRYID))

If Not conItem Is Nothing Then ' we have a conversation in which we should be able to match the reply
    Set ConTable = conItem.GetTable
    ConArray = ConTable.GetArray(ConTable.GetRowCount)
    LastVerb = oMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED)
    Select Case LastVerb
        Case EXCHIVERB_REPLYTOSENDER, EXCHIVERB_REPLYTOALL ', EXCHIVERB_FORWARD ' not interested in forwarded messages
            VerbTime = oMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME)
            VerbTime = oMailItem.PropertyAccessor.UTCToLocalTime(VerbTime) ' convert to local time
            ' Debug.Print "Reply to " & oMailItem.Subject & " sent on (local time): " & VerbTime
            For lp = 0 To UBound(ConArray)
                If ConArray(lp, 4) = "IPM.Note" Then ' it is a mailitem
                    Set MsgItem = ns.GetItemFromID(ConArray(lp, 0)) 'mail item to check against
                    If Not MsgItem.Sender Is Nothing Then
                        If OriginatorID = MsgItem.Sender.ID Then
                            Clockdrift = DateDiff("s", VerbTime, MsgItem.SentOn)
                            If Clockdrift >= 0 And Clockdrift < 300 Then ' Allow for a clock drift of up to 300 seconds. This may be overgenerous
                                Set GetReply = MsgItem
                                Exit For ' only interested in first matching     reply
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Case Else
    End Select
End If
' as we exit function GetMsg is either Nothing or the reply we are interested in
End Function

Public Sub ListIt()
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim myItem As Object ' item may not necessarily be a mailitem
Dim myReplyItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myFolder As Folder
Dim xlRow As Long

Set ns = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") ' Initialise Outlook access
Set myFolder = ns.PickFolder() ' for the sake of this example we just pick a folder.

InitSheet Sheet1 ' initialise the spreadsheet

xlRow = 3
For Each myItem In myFolder.Items
    If myItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set myReplyItem = GetReply(myItem) ' this example only deals with mailitems
        If Not myReplyItem Is Nothing Then ' we found a reply
            PopulateSheet Sheet1, myItem, myReplyItem, xlRow
            xlRow = xlRow + 1
        End If
    End If
    DoEvents ' cheap and nasty way to allow other things to happen
Next

MsgBox "Congrats! You now know your Average Response time! Kudos my friend!"

End Sub

Private Sub InitSheet(mySheet As Worksheet)
With mySheet
    .Cells.Clear
    .Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Received"
    .Cells(2, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "From"
    .Cells(2, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "Subject"
    .Cells(2, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "Date/Time"
    .Cells(1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "Replied"
    .Cells(2, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "From"
    .Cells(2, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "To"
    .Cells(2, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "Subject"
    .Cells(2, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "Date/Time"
    .Cells(2, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "Response Time"
    .Cells(2, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "Categories"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateSheet(mySheet As Worksheet, myItem As MailItem,     myReplyItem As MailItem, xlRow As Long)
Dim recips() As String
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim lp As Long

With mySheet
    .Cells(xlRow, 1).FormulaR1C1 = myItem.SenderEmailAddress
    .Cells(xlRow, 2).FormulaR1C1 = myItem.Subject
    .Cells(xlRow, 3).FormulaR1C1 = myItem.ReceivedTime
    .Cells(xlRow, 4).FormulaR1C1 = myReplyItem.SenderEmailAddress
    .Cells(xlRow, 9).FormulaR1C1 = myItem.Categories
        '.Cells(xlRow, 4).FormulaR1C1 = myReplyItem.Sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) ' I prefer to see the SMTP address
    For lp = 0 To myReplyItem.Recipients.Count - 1
        ReDim Preserve recips(lp) As String
        recips(lp) = myReplyItem.Recipients(lp + 1).Address
    Next
    .Cells(xlRow, 5).FormulaR1C1 = Join(recips, vbCrLf)
    .Cells(xlRow, 6).FormulaR1C1 = myReplyItem.Subject
    .Cells(xlRow, 7).FormulaR1C1 = myReplyItem.SentOn
    .Cells(xlRow, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-5]"
    .Cells(xlRow, 8).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"

 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is it dying? What are the specs of the m/c on which you ran it? How much of scaling up did you do? Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: also, what is the end result of this code supposed to be?

Comment: The code doesn't seem to fail at any particular point, while in some instances it will input data into the cells. I didn't measure the scaling up, but that's a valid point, I'll look at which point the volume becomes to much. The end result should be a time between when the 1st email came in and then replied to. is there some sort of Cache that needs to be cleared?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your subs as Private instead of Public, that solves it most of the times.